# Google map integration with php using multiple location

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation

I want to display google map according to entered multiple locations in the form using php?I tried to find google api for php.Can anyone give some idea how to do this?

Comment: Why use php? Is it absolutely necessary for some other reason for the user to submit a form to your server? Why not just read the form inputs via javascript and do the geocoding on the client side? You are still leaving us with a lot more questions for you than just these.... but alas here is one place to look if you must use php: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: Actually I have such type of requirement.I have a form which takes 4 addresses and when i submit that form. Result should be google map with that 4 address marking points.i dnt know how to do this?

Comment: I tried from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/ and GoogleMapAPI-2.5 code.